# Lua modules inheritance

Tags: oop, inheritance, nginx, lua

Need your help with modules inheritance in Lua .

Let's say I've got 2 modules:

The 1st one is "Parent" It defines 1 field called "port" and method "connect" that uses port & domain fields to connect to some service. I wanna define the 2nd field (domain) in Child module, not in Parent one. Or at least to override this field by Child module.

```
module('Parent', package.seeall)

port = 1234

function connect() 
   ngx.say("connecting to "..domain..":"..port.."\n")

end
```

Note that "*domain*" variable *is not defined* here!

Now let's see the 2nd one, it's "Child":

```
local base = _G

module('Child', package.seeall)

local Parent = base.require('Parent')
base.setmetatable(Child, { __index = Parent })

domain     = '127.0.0.1'
```

And here goes main lua code creating Child instance:

```
local Child = require "Child"

Child.connect()
```

The problem is that variable defined in *Child* module is invisible for the method defined in *Parent* module.. I need to change this behavior to let Parent routines code see variables defined in Child module.. Is that possible?
Can i copy *Child*'s namespace to Parent module somehow?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://lua-users.org/wiki/TemplatePattern

Comment: Note that `module` is [generally considered harmful now](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaModuleFunctionCritiqued).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not particularly familiar with Lua modules, but it seems to me the right solution is to redefine the method as `function connect(self)` and then access `port` and `domain` off of `self`, which will be the package.

```
function connect(self)
    ngx.say("connecting to "..self.domain..":"..self.port.."\n")
end
-- this could also be written as function Parent:connect()
```

...

```
local Child = require "Child"

Child:connect()
```

That's certainly how I'd do it if I were just setting up regular table inheritance without modules.

Comment: @user1116342 consider accepting his answer (by clicking the check mark) to give him some credit and show future visitors that (and how) your problem has been solved